# Clicking the checkbox and changing database Boolean value in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have my database connected through my code, the column I'm trying to change is called "Sent".
The checkbox is inside a table so it's more organized.
I'm trying to do it so when the user clicks the checkbox the database gets automatically changed to 1 if its checked and to 0 if its unchecked. The variable conn is the connection I've made.
Here's what I have:

```
<?php
    $execItems = $conn->query("SELECT Sent FROM Schools");
    while($infoItems = $execItems->fetch_array())
    {
        echo "<tr><td>
              <input type=\"checkbox\"".($infoItems['Sent']?' checked':'')."\" />
              </td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: you are just echoing the database values here as html. if you want to change the values in DB after click then you have to submit the value post selection using PHP Form Submit or Ajax. it won't happen magically.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek It always thought every computer has a unicorn inside that exactly understands what a user wants? But in case the unicorn isn't home, OP could start with [this manual](https://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this like below.

```
  <?php
        $execItems = $conn->query("SELECT Sent FROM Schools");
        while($infoItems = $execItems->fetch_array())
        {
           $checked = ($infoItems['Sent'] == 1 ? ' checked' : '');

            echo "<tr><td>
                          <input type='checkbox'  ".$checked."/>
                          </td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a function on `onChange` event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checked;
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked"))
    {
        checked=1;        
    }
    else
    {
        checked=0;
    }
   //Call Ajax here to update in database
});
});
```